# Grails Database migration - How to remove a specific row?

Tags: sql, grails, database-migration

I have to do a manual migration for deleting a specific row in table called "Types".

The row has a value "Super" in the value column. How should I write the `changeSet` for this?

I tried:

```
databaseChangeLog = {

changeSet(author: "sara (generated)", id: "1432343423-8") {
   delete(tableName: "Types") {
        where(value: "Super")
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "changeSet"? Whats wrong with `DELETE Types WHERE Value='Super'`? Also post the database type - Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: looks like you posted some JSON. What do you run this in? what tool?

Comment: it's plugin which called Grails Db Migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `sql`:

`changeSet(author: "you", id: "1437421083434-8") {
        sql("DELETE FROM types WHERE value='Super';")
}`

Comment: I prefer to use SQL for DML changes but there isn't anything wrong with using delete. I guess you should have `where("value = 'Super'")`. See  http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/delete.html

Comment: the problem was that I use the id of Types in other table...this is why I got error of foreignKey guess. The problem with the SQL delete is unsafe